# I want 2 Divs or Table Cells Floating next to each, one to have display: inline and the other to fill rest of the row

Tags: html, css

What I want:

[image]

What I have achieved:

[image]

I have floated both DIV tags next to each other (I have also tried using tables). I want the HR line to fill the rest of horizontal space that the title doesn't utilise.

I don't want to use fixed widths or % widths.

I have tried most things I know of to table cells. The best way I can describe the property I want is similar to display: inline with headers, so it stops it going full width, but instead the table would wrap round it to leave the HR table cell to fill the rest of the row.

Here is some code: Didn't attach originally as was only Tables wasn't much to it, chucked out un-relevant bits

```
 .certificatetitle { font-weight: 100; font-size: 16px; }

 .collapsed .line {  height: 40px;  }
 .line { height: 40px;   }
 .line hr { color: #f69f1a; background-color: #f69f1a; border-color: #f69f1a; height: 1px; }


<table class="certificatebar" height="40px">
    <tr>
        <td class="certicon" width="30px"></td><td class="certificatetitle">Microsoft Office</td><td class="line"><hr /></td><td class="dropdown" width="20"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Show some code please

Comment: just post your html that you tried and you will receive help in no time

Comment: Coded added, just simple tables really. I just wanted to know how to get .certificatetitle to 'Display Inline' so .line would auto fill the rest of the table row. Instead currently they seem to either one takes up the larger portion or the 50% / 50%

Answer (score -1, accepted):

May be this can help you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <style>
        table.certificatebar { width: 100%; }
        .certificatetitle { font-weight: 100; font-size: 16px; }
        .collapsed .line { height: 40px; }
        .line { height: 40px; width: 100%; }
        .line hr { 
            color: #f69f1a; 
            background-color: #f69f1a; 
            border-color: #f69f1a; 
            height: 1px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<table class="certificatebar" height="40px">
    <tr>
        <td class="certicon" width="30px"></td>
        <td class="certificatetitle">Microsoft&nbsp;Office</td>
        <td class="line"><hr/></td>
        <td class="dropdown" width="20"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Tables should only be used for presenting tabular data, not layout.  Just because the OP originally provided a table doesn't mean its the best choice.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this entirely with a single element, allowing it to retain semantic purity (not to mention easy maintenance in the future).

http://cssdeck.com/labs/kw3ivdam

```
<h1>Microsoft Office</h1>

h1 {
    /* add "door" logo image as background here */
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

h1:before { /* element holding your carrot image */
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    content: ' ';
    right: 0;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -15px; /* half of your height */
    width: 30px; /* width of bg image */
    height: 30px; /* height of bg image */
    background: url(http://placehold.it/30x30) no-repeat white;
}

h1:after { /* element creating your `hr` effect */
    display: inline-block;
    content: " ";
    border-bottom: 1px solid goldenrod;
    width: 100%;
    margin-right: -50%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```